# How to properly write dollar sign on xaringan?

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

I am using Xaringan slides. I want to write dollar values like $10-$5=$5 using math notation.

My code is the following:

```
$ \$10-\$5 = \$5 $.
```

However, the code will not generate the outcome in mathematical way as I wanted.

I know it works with double dollar sign `$$`, but I want to the result stay on the same line.

Also I don't want to put USD or CAD instead of $. Any tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `\$` just define a macro using latex syntax `\newcommand`

```
---
output: xaringan::moon_reader
---

# Defining inline math expression  containing currency dollar sign

<!---- This is a macro for Mathjax ----->
$$\newcommand\dollars{\$}$$
<!---- --------------------------- ----->

This line conttain inline expression $\dollars10 - \dollars5 = \dollars5$
```

which looks like,

[image: xaringan_with_dollar_sign_in_inline_Math_Equation]